# Draw surface graph

Tags: data-visualization

Does any know how to draw a graph like this:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Ivsrf.gif]

Which programs can do that? I'm a developer so I've no problem on formatting a complex files so that a software can handle it.

Comment: SAS is one that can.

Comment: Look up for "response surface plot" on Google; e.g., if you're willing to use R, [Surface Plots in the `rsm` Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsm/vignettes/rsm-plots.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots can do it. R (packages such as lattice, misc3d and [others](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753:boaz1reyxd4&newwindow=1&q=3d%20surface%20plot&sa=Search&cof=FORID:11&siteurl=www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%253Aboaz1reyxd4&q=3d%2bplotting&newwindow=1&cof=FORID%253A11)), Matlab, Python (see matplotlib), Wolfram Alpha / Mathematica... I'd use whatever your most comfortable in.

See [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plot+3d).

Comment: "these questions" link is wrong. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Fixed. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Since it wasn't mentioned yet: You could have a look at [gnuplot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/).